# var name = new object() vs this.name = new object

Tags: javascript, oop

In this case, I define an object called DropHandler

```
function DropHandler(){}
DropHandler.prototype={
    AllowDrop : AllowDrop,
    Drag : Drag,
    Drop : Drop
}
```

And want to create an instance of DropHandler in Admin object.But what is the different between the following code? code (2) seems can not be used in this case, it will get a undefined type error

```
var BackendAdmin = function(){
    this.DropHandler = new DropHandler();//(1);
    var DropHandler = new DropHandler();//(2);
}
```

Comment: The two answers cover why the `var` version doesn't work, but I think it's worth noting more generally that the convention (not enforced by the language) is that constructor function names start with a capital letter, `function DropHandler()` and instances start with a lowercase letter, e.g., `var dropHandler` or `var myDropHandler` or `this.dropHandler`. Not only does this make it immediately obvious whether a particular name refers to the constructor or an instance it prevents the problem you were having since JS is case sensitive and the names are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in (1) you assign new `DropHandler` object to `DropHandler` property of `BackendAdmin` instance, and in (2) you assign it to a local `DropHandler` variable.

You get error because `var` is moved to the top of the method automatically (it is called *Hoisting*) by the interpreter and your code in fact looks like:

```
var BackendAdmin = function(){
    var DropHandler;
    this.DropHandler = new DropHandler();//(1);
    DropHandler = new DropHandler();//(2);
}
```

So you try to call the function, which is actually overwriten by an empty variable.

PS: cannot find really good explanation of JS variables hoisting, but this is something from google: http://blog.binarymist.net/2011/11/14/scoping-hoisting-in-javascript/

Comment: but I cannot assign the DropHandler to, it will give me a error massage says DropHandler in new DropHandler() is undefined

Comment: @Panda Yang: yep, see my update - the function is not defined, because `var DropHandler;` has overwritten it

Comment: Yes, because you did not assign a value to `DropHandler`! E.g.: `var a; a = new a();` => `a is undefined`

Comment: I see, in fact, I want to use var to create a local instance of DropHandler, but seems I user the same name of object DropHandler so javascript will auto-replace the object DropHandler which I define it above. Is that right? because when I change it to var myDropHandler = new DropHandler() it works

Comment: @Panda Yang: for `var DropHandler = ...` javascript engine hoists the variable declaration to the top of the function, so after scope resolution `DropHandler` variable is `undefined`. And when you invoke `undefined` you get a error.

Comment: Or to explain more simply without worrying about technical details of hoisting, you can't have two variables or functions with the same name in the same scope. Which is why renaming that variable fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two separate entities (a local variable and a function in scope) with the same name and have them still be seprately reachable entities.

When you create the local variable, it temporarily overrides/hides the function of the same name in that scope and that function name is no longer accessible in that scope.  Change the name of either one and it should work like this:

```
var BackendAdmin = function(){
    this.DropHandler = new DropHandler();//(1);
    var myDropHandler = new DropHandler();//(2);
}
```

`this.DropHandler` works because in that case `DropHandler` is a property on another object and thus separate from the `DropHandler()` function.

Comment: actually, I use one of them to create an instance, but (1) works fine and (2) will get an error message.

Comment: @PandaYang - (1) Works because it doesn't create a variable in that function scope, it creates a property on the object referenced by `this`.